# unix shell to search for word and delete 2 words after the word

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

```
sed '/KEYWORD/,$d'
```

Input:

```
ALTER TABLE TEMP ADD CONSTRAINT temp_pk PRIMARY KEY (temp_id) DISABLED;
ALTER TABLE TEMP2 ADD CONSTRAINT temp_pk2 PRIMARY KEY (temp_id) DISABLED;
```

Need to search all lines in a file with word ADD and remove next two words

Output needed is:

```
ALTER TABLE TEMP ADD  PRIMARY KEY (temp_id) DISABLED;
ALTER TABLE TEMP2 ADD PRIMARY KEY (temp_id) DISABLED;
```

Answer (score 0):

Always write regular expressions that are as specific as possible; this minimizes the odds of matching something you didn't mean to match and corrupting the file.  In this case, that means "don't just match ADD, match ADD CONSTRAINT foo PRIMARY KEY."

```
perl -pe 's/\bADD\s+CONSTRAINT\s+[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\s+PRIMARY\s+KEY\b/ADD PRIMARY KEY/g'
```

This uses perl instead of sed to get more powerful regular expressions; specifically, the `\b`, `\s`, and `+` symbols are not available in all versions of sed.

Comment: if my filename is test.sql .how to put above to change in the whole file

Comment: Same as you would with `sed`: put `< test.sql > test-edited.sql` at the end of the command line.

Answer (score 0):

***sed*** solution:

```
sed -i 's/\<ADD [^[:space:]]* *[^[:space:]]*/ADD/' file
```

`file` contents after modification:

```
ALTER TABLE TEMP ADD PRIMARY KEY (temp_id) DISABLED;
ALTER TABLE TEMP2 ADD PRIMARY KEY (temp_id) DISABLED;
```

---

- `\<` - matches the beginning of a word
- `[^[:space:]]*` - matches any character except whitespace

Answer (score 0):

With GNU or OSX sed for `-E` to enable EREs:

```
$ sed -E 's/(ADD)\s\S+\s\S+/\1/' file
ALTER TABLE TEMP ADD PRIMARY KEY (temp_id) DISABLED;
ALTER TABLE TEMP2 ADD PRIMARY KEY (temp_id) DISABLED;
```

Answer (score 0):

**awk** of course:

```
$ awk -v key="ADD" '$0~" " key " " {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
                                    printf "%s%s", $i, i==NF ? ORS:OFS
                                    if ($i==key) i+=2}}' file
ALTER TABLE TEMP ADD PRIMARY KEY (temp_id) DISABLED;
ALTER TABLE TEMP2 ADD PRIMARY KEY (temp_id) DISABLED;
```